# Надпись «голосовать за удаление этого сообщения»

Tags: дефект

Складывается впечатление, что текст надписи у своего сообщения немного противоречит смыслу данного действия. Скрин:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст сообщения:

> голосовать за удаление этого сообщения

По факту я не голосую за удаление, а просто удаляю свое сообщение. Не так ли?

Comment: Но такая же ссылка есть у каждого, кто видит сообщение (и имеет достаточно репутации). Просто у вас решающий голос.

Comment: @Nofate, я догадывался, что так и есть. Но ведь разница есть, когда я удаляю и голосую за удаление.

Comment: Вроде как вся эта свистопляска работает через голосование, даже в timeline показывает, что удаление с помощью голосования даже когда сам удаляешь. Например, вот [такая тема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288944/339911) встречается.

Comment: Все верно. В логах будет "удалён *@username* с помощью голосования"

Comment: @Nofate и это вводит в заблуждение на самом деле.

Comment: @alexolut , думаю это следствие того, что движок делали "программисты для программистов".

Comment: @Nofate, просто на Мете я могу такой вопрос задать, внести предложение, которое рассмотрят, ведь для этого она и есть. Каким будет решение относительно моего вопроса? Удалять, может быть я увижу ответ, или что?

Comment: @DenisBubnov решение, скорее всего, будет метка [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано]. На нашей мете про дефекты движка лучше вообще не писать, а сразу в MSE оформлять.

Comment: Конечно можете. Но шансы изменить что-то в движке малы. Может быть удастся выбить отдельную строку локализации хинта для случаев удаления своего сообщения.

Comment: Если @NicolasChabanovsky это проэскалирует.

Comment: @Nofate, тогда я оставляю вопрос. Если что, Вы проинформируйте меня по поводу дальнейших действий, ну или я вам напомню ))

Comment: @alexolut, технически это, конечно, by-design.

Comment: Просто за собственные вопросы у вас решающий голос при удалении. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin звучит как оправдание :D

Comment: Это не проблема перевода. На MSE [описан соответствующий дефект](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275936/339911) с точки формулировки текста.